# Eye cursor fixed at the center of FOV and no hand/gesture recognition on HoloLens

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, gesture-recognition, mrtk

my HoloLens 2 app runs perfectly in Unity: the simulated hand gestures / speech input are recognized and the menus/holograms are responsive. I have literally 0 warnings/errors.
The solution builds without any errors whatsoever and the app packages are created in Visual Studio again without any errors.

Once I deploy on HoloLens I am experiencing a very strange behavior: I see the gaze cursor fixed in the middle of the FOV, my hands are not recognized and no gestures are possible. I just see my start menu fixed on the ground like in the attached picture. The menu is supposed to be triggered when I open my palm (HandMenu prefab from MRTK). Also a red frame is displayed with performance infos. The only feedback I get is a click, when I perform the air tap gesture, but again nothing happens.
[What is see on HoloLens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3Nlf.jpg)

My configuration is as follows:

- Unity 2020.2.6f1 with UWP build support
- Visual Studio 16.9.2 (ARM64 Build)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.19041.0)
- Necessary Packages like MRTK Foundation, Examples... and OpenXR installed in Unity using the MRTK Feature Tool [Unity Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fdWe.png)
- Scene configured using Mixed Reality > OpenXR > Apply recommended project + scene settings
- XR Rig on the root configured automatically
- [Unity Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlV7T.png)
- [Unity Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bI75B.png)
- I tried building with every possible profile like DefaultOpenXRConfigurationProfile, DefaultHoloLens2ConfigurationProfile, DefaultHololens2XRSDKConfigurationProfile...

Has anybody noticed the same behavior? Does anyone have any suggestions? I have spent the past two days trying to figure it out, but without luck. Any help is welcome.

Thanks a lot,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue about Gestures that can't work with OpenXR or XR SDK:[Gestures do not work on HL2 with OpenXR or XR SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/9492). And the reply is the legacy XR pipeline is currently the only one that supports gestures, so an option to work with Gestures on HL2 right now is to use the Unity version with legacy XR pipeline .

Comment: Thanks for redirecting me to the solution. That solved my problem!
I downgraded my project (Unity 2019.4, Legacy XR Pipeline, Old Configuration Profiles) and now everything works as it should. Adding support for the new OpenXR should be top priority I think.